# python efficient way to compare item in list of tuples

Tags: python, data-structures

Is there an efficient way without for loops to compare if an item inside a list of tuples is the same across all tuples in Python?

```
lst_tups = [('Hello', 1, 'Name:'), ('Goodbye', 1, 'Surname:'), ('See you!', 1, 'Time:')]
```

The expected output is Return all unique values for item in index 1 of the tuple

```
unique = list()

for i in lst_tups:
    item = i[1]
    unique.append(item)


set(unique)
    

Expected Output: 
>>

Unique values: [1]

True if all are equal, otherwise False
```

Comment: Please add the expected output?

Comment: Did you mean that the expected output will be either `True` or `False`? But in the case of `index 1` in `lst_tups` the expected output will be `True`?

Comment: But you want to know if all are equals?

Comment: `res = all(lst_tups[0][1] == b[1] for b in lst_tups)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution without using `for` loop.

```
import operator
lst_tups = [('Hello', 1, 'Name:'), ('Goodbye', 1, 'Surname:'), ('See you!', 1, 'Time:')]
unique = set(map(operator.itemgetter(1),lst_tups))
print(unique)  # {1}
```

Please consider above code and write if is *an efficient way* according to your standards.

Answer (score 5):

I think the set [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-comprehension) is an acceptable way:

```
>>> unique = {i[1] for i in lst_tups}
>>> unique
{1}
```

If you want to avoid the for loop anyway, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) (for large lists, it will be slightly more efficient than set comprehension, but the readability is worse):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> unique = set(map(itemgetter(1), lst_tups))
>>> unique
{1}
```

Then you can confirm whether the elements are all the same by judging whether the length of the set is 1:

```
>>> len(unique) == 1
True
```

If you only want to get the result or the item you want to compare is unhashable (such as dict), you can use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) (in Python3.10+) to compare adjacent elements to judge (but that doesn't mean it will be faster):

```
>>> from itertools import pairwise, starmap
>>> from operator import itemgetter, eq
>>> all(i[1] == j[1] for i, j in pairwise(lst_tups))
True
>>> all(starmap(eq, pairwise(map(itemgetter(1), lst_tups))))
True
```

---

According to the questions raised in the comment area, when your unique item is in another position or the element itself in the sequence, the above method only needs to be slightly modified to achieve the purpose, so here are two more general solutions:

```
def all_equal_by_set(iterable):
    return len(set(iterable)) == 1


def all_equal_by_compare(iterable):
    return all(starmap(eq, pairwise(iterable)))
```

Then you just need to call them like this:

```
>>> all_equal_by_set(map(itemgetter(1), lst_tups))
True
>>> all_equal_by_set(tup[1] for tup in lst_tups)   # Note that here is a generator expression, which is no longer comprehension.
True
>>> all_equal_by_compare(map(itemgetter(1), lst_tups))
True
>>> all_equal_by_compare(tup[1] for tup in lst_tups)
True
```

Comment: @matt.aurelio the set comprehension here is the more "pythonic" way - shorter, easier to read, and also faster

Comment: Question - what if the *unique* item is at different *position* (not *fixed* 1 in the case)?  It assumed it's the *same* index position here.

Comment: @DanielHao Assuming the position is n, you just need to replace all 1 with n, such as `{i[n] ...}` and `itemgetter(n)`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate on starmap and pairwise functions role in your example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and slicing with three step : `[1::3]`.

```
from itertools import chain
res = list(chain.from_iterable(lst_tups))[1::3]
print(set(res))

# If you want to print True if all are equal, otherwise False
if len(set(res)) == 1:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

---

```
{1}
```